# Storing Files to Local Disk in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension to extract images in a web page and store them into local disk. Now I have got the URLs of all the images, how can I store them into local disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be solved by using [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) but it is not recommanded

> NPAPI plugin has the full permissions of the current user and is not sandboxed or shielded from malicious input by Google Chrome in any way

Answer (score 0):

1. The link to the post on html5rocks is a good one - BUT in your case I guess you want to be able to save to the local file system and not the location that morden browser let you write to (btw, it's not virtual filesystem but a location on the disk).
2. You cannot save directly to any location on the local file system (security) - However, if you need to save images.. use this little hack: you can open them in a new tab (e.g. add to their link target="_blank") and in this case Chrome will save them to the default location (e.g. ~userHome/Downloads on mac)